# Using JQuery and Prototype in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Several of my pages use both JQuery and Protoype. Since I upgraded to version 1.3 of JQuery this appears to be causing problems, because both libraries define a function named '$'.

JQuery provides a function noConflict() which relinquishes control of $ to other libraries that may be using it. So it seems like I need to go through all my pages that look like this:

```
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

and change them to look like this:

```
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var $j = jQuery;
    </script>
</head>
```

I should then be able to use '$' for Prototype and '$j' (or 'jQuery') for JQuery. I'm not entirely happy about duplicating these 2 lines of code in every relevant page, and expect that at some point somebody is likely to forget to add them to a new page. I'd prefer to be able to do the following

- Create a file j`query-noconflict.js` which "includes" `jquery.js` and the 2 lines of code shown above
- Import `jquery-noconflict.js` (instead of `jquery.js`) in all my JSP/HTML pages

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to include one JS file in another, in the manner I've described? Of course an alternate solution is simply to add the 2 lines of code above to jquery.js directly, but if I do that I'll need to remember to do it every time I upgrade JQuery.

Comment: Does answer I provided works for you?

Comment: Dunno, it's been 3 years since I asked this question...

Comment: Ok.. :) I missed that.. :) But I think the principle is correct as I tried it out...

Comment: Obviously this is old, but I had a situation where I had to change 5 lines of code in 63 html files (I didn't build the website).  Some regex replace, and replace in files did the trick in a few seconds.  Notepad++ will do it to a limited degree, and submlime text editor did it like a champ.

Comment: @DavidHobs: +1 for Sublime! It's the best thing since sliced bread!

Answer (score 19):

Currently you can do something like this:

```
<head>          
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
</head>
```

Then, use jQuery as `$j()` and Prototype's `$()`.

Comment: This was very helpful to me on a similar issue. Thank you jmonteiro :)

Answer (score 5):

It would seem that the most simple answer would be to bite the bullet, and include your noConflict lines. Of course if your pages aren't using a shared header, that solution might not be the best.

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked fine:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var $j = jQuery;
```

Now use `$j` in place of `$` for your jQuery code, like:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#div_id').innerfade({
         // some stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I went through this for a while.  It is very annoying and in the end I decided to weed out all of my old Prototype stuff and replace it with jQuery.  I do like the way Prototype handles some Ajax tasks but it wasn't worth the trade off of maintaining all of the no conflict stuff.

Comment: +1 It's always a good idea to reduce the used frameworks. Not only in terms of conflicts but also in terms of a light-weight application event if it requires some refactoring to eliminate prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just include the `jQuery = noConflict()` code in the jquery.js source file? Why would it need to be defined that way?

Answer (score 2):

Just as a note to others that stumble upon this. The solutions are described here (mentioning prototype specifically):
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
</script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var $j = jQuery;
</script>
```

or

```
var scripty = document.createElement('script');
scripty.href="/obp/js/jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scripty);
jQuery.noConflict();
var $j = jQuery;
```

**EDIT:**

I tried out this suggestion but the last 2 lines produce the error

```
jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: You need to specify a callback when the script loads to run the noconflict code... just do a .appendChild(scripty)
scripty.onload = setNoconflict;
function setNoconflict(){ jQuery.noConflict(); $j = jQuery; }

Comment: @jacobangel your first example works, but I removed a typo (see diff) and made a correction: it's important to close the script tag after `document.write(..)` and open up a new one where `jQuery.noConflict()` is in. Otherwise jQuery is not defined because `document.write` is appending the jQuery-script *after* the current script block.

Answer (score 1):

You could call jquery first and then set

```
var $j = jQuery;
```

prototype will take control of `$` in this case.

Or, you could just refer to jQuery by using the full jQuery function name (jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Your `jquery-noconflict.js` should look like this (be sure that all is in one line):

```
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/obp/js/jquery.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">jQuery.noConflict();var $j = jQuery;</script>");
```

... and than your include (as you already pointed out) should look like this:

```
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/prototype.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/obp/js/jquery-noconflict.js"></script>
</head>
```

This solution solves all your requirements I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd drop my no conflict code into a JavaScript include file like you opined about above, and then figure out some process where I'd be setting these things I need to include in all my pages in one central place. If you are working with straight HTML files and you don't have any kind of templating/scripting capability server-side for what gets included in a document, there's always the possibility of doing a Server-Side Include.

Either way, the pain you'll experience updating each of your pages this time will come back again when you need to update your analytics code or the site footer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prototype below jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="news/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="news/jquery.easynews.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="lb/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lb/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lb/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="lb/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in this case the jQuery function will create a problem, so you can use this to solve the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();
     var JQ = jQuery;//rename $ function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load it in your `public/javascript/application.js`

```
jQuery.noConflict();

var $j = jQuery;
```

This is also a good article that may be helpful.

[JQuery & Prototype working together](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-prototype-to-jquery/)