# Prototype and jQuery together?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I noticed that a certain script I use relies on prototype. (Lightbox 2) Will it work together on the same page as jQuery? Is there way to make sure that they don;t conflict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using JQuery and Prototype in the same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451362/using-jquery-and-prototype-in-the-same-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [huge number of lightbox clones](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/), why not choose a jQuery one? Regardless of avoiding conflicts between the libraries, having two JS libraries on one page is a *lot* to download.

Answer (score 9):

You can but you need to take [special steps](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) if you're using the `$()` special function. Basically it comes down to the order you call libraries and/or calling `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery.noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) so that you are required to make calls using the jQuery object explicitly (i.e. `jQuery('#selector')` instead of the `$` alias.