# How can I adress only one of the articles in Javascript (AJAX)?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

At my website I have clickable hidden meta tags like page views or Google requests under every article.

This is the code I use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();
     $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
 });
 </script>
```

And this code for PHP:

```
<p class="postmetadata"><a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide">[Show/hide meta data]</a></p>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<p class="postmetadata">Aufrufe: <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?> </p>
<p class="postmetadata"><?php if(function_exists('stt_terms_list')) echo stt_terms_list() ;?></p>
<p class="postmetadata"><?php if (function_exists('backlinks')) backlinks(); ?></p>
<br>
</div>
```

I use Wordpress. The problem is, if I click on "Show/hide meta data" every article shows the meta data. I only want the meta data of the article I clicked. This is [my website](http://www.abitur-lernhilfen.de/).

You have to click on the german "[Zeige/Verstecke Meta-Daten]", which is equal to "[Show/hide meta data]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery method [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/), this will work right now:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Using jQuery method [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), this will work even if you rearrange the order of the elements:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

Using jQuery method [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), this works even if you rearrange the elements depths:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.span-8').find('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

---

Also, for jQuery/Prototype conflicts, see this: [Prototype and jQuery together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997401/prototype-and-jquery-together)

The simplest solution is to create a temporary context:

```
(function($){
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    });
}(jQuery));
```