# Rails 3.1 auto_complete plugin gives strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete, rails-3.1

I'm using auto_complete plugin:

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

I have installed the gem and added require line in my manifest file as instructed:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
```

Having done just this, firebug gives me this error message:

```
$("input[data-autocomplete]") is null
```

and error is traced to this line in autocomplete-rails.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("input[data-autocomplete]").railsAutocomplete()})...
```

I'm using:

```
Rails 3.1.0
Ruby 1.9.2
```

Has anyone experienced the same? I just installed and required the gem and not even started doing the changes to the controller / view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just incase, did you try restarting your server?

Comment: I don't know if this has something to do for my need for prototype libraries.

Comment: See [using JQuery and Prototype on the same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451362/using-jquery-and-prototype-in-the-same-page) why that could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but no help there. I haven't found yet a solution to run this plugin with Prototype enabled.

Comment: Only soluton I have found to this is not to use Prototype library at the same time. I have added noConflict statements, but they are not helping. I have now changed my Prototype-related code to vanilla JS or Jquery. Hmmm... not a good solution, but I needed to do this change eventually. This was a good trigger for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Prototype library at the same time with Jquery. Unfortunately this was only solution i could come up with. I tried noConflict statements and loading libraries in different order. I'm accepting this answer now, because there haven't been any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete-rails.js will search an element with attribute 'data-autocomplete' after the document is ready.

As you did not added the auto complete field in your view page it shows null.
You can add auto field with auto complete in two ways.

1.Using form_for

```
form_for @product do |f|
  f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path
end
```

This will generate an html

```
<input type="text" data-autocomplete="products/autocomplete_brand_name">
```

2.Using form_tag

```
form_tag 'some/path'
  autocomplete_field_tag 'address', '', address_autocomplete_path, :size => 75
end
```

Nothing you did wrong.You are in the middle of development.This problem will be solved when you added autocomplete filed in your view page as described in the gem.

cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no help there. I tried also adding stuff to controller and view, but no help. Seriously, is that gem working like that? It will give me a Javascript error if I don't have certain named input element on my page? Are you sure? I would think that any gem shouldn't intentionally crash my site if it's not in use.

Comment: You are right.I have implemented this gem recently in my app.But i have only jQuery library.I just added prototype in my app and getting the exact error what you have mentioned here.So its due to the conflict between jQuery and prototype library.Remove prototype and check.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. I can't directly remove the prototype, because I have many classes implemented Prototype-way, but I'll create a new project and try to find the workaround. Let me get back to you, thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to test this out. It seems that Prototype - jquery combo is messing things up in here. I've always had noConflict in place and now I've been trying loading libraries in different order. Unfortunately I can't accept your answer, cause it would require remove Prototype completely. Thanks!